Vertical navbar on left unable to use controls to the right of it
This navbar is placed vertically on the left of the page. If I leave out fixed-top the content on the right is pushed under the control.
If fixed-top is added the content aligns perfectly to the right, but I cannot access any items like links and searchbar that are directly to the right of the navbar - content under the navbar height works as expected. It's just like the controls are disabled.
Any ideas?
This is what it looks like (click to enlarge)

UPDATE - Here is the code for the navbar. The full navbar is nearly 500 lines long so just added the first few lines.


.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container-menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  clear: both;
}

.mcd-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  /*height: 100px;*/
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  /* == */
  width: 250px;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*float:left;*/
}

.mcd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: #777;
  /*text-align: center;
       border-right: 1px solid #E7E7E7;*/
  /* == */
  text-align: left;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li a i {
  /* margin-bottom: 25px;*/
  /*display: block;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;*/
  /* == */
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  /* == */
}


/* == */

.mcd-menu li a p {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}


/* == */

.mcd-menu li a strong {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mcd-menu li a small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.mcd-menu li a i,
.mcd-menu li a strong,
.mcd-menu li a small {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.mcd-menu li:hover>a i {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.mcd-menu li:hover a strong {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: moveFromLeft 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromLeft 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: moveFromLeft 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: moveFromLeft 300ms ease-in-out;
  animation: moveFromLeft 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.mcd-menu li:hover a small {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease-in-out;
  animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.mcd-menu li:hover>a {
  color: #e67e22;
}

.mcd-menu li a.active {
  position: relative;
  color: #e67e22;
  border: 0;
  /*border-top: 4px solid #e67e22;
       border-bottom: 4px solid #e67e22;
       margin-top: -4px;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;
  /* == */
  border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
  border-right: 4px solid #e67e22;
  margin: 0 -4px;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li a.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;
         left: 45%;
      border-top: 5px solid #e67e22;
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 5px solid transparent;*/
  /* == */
  top: 42%;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  /* == */
}


/* == */

.mcd-menu li a.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}


/* == */

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTop {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(200%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(200%);
    -o-transform: translateY(200%);
    transform: translateY(200%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
    -o-transform: translateX(200%);
    transform: translateX(200%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.mcd-menu li ul,
.mcd-menu li ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  /*border-top: 4px solid #e67e22;*/
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  /*top: 130px;*/
  z-index: 1000;
  /* == */
  left: 280px;
  top: 0px;
  /*<-------------------------- Set at 0px ------------- this positions the element - */
  border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /*top: -8px;
  left: 23%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;*/
  /* == */
  top: var(--vtop);
  /*<----------------- Set at 25 px ---------------- this positions the pointer*/
  left: -9px;
  border-right: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li:hover>ul,
.mcd-menu li ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  /*top: 100px;*/
  /* == */
  left: 250px;
  /* == */
}


/*.mcd-menu li ul li {
 float: none;
}*/

.mcd-menu li ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
  /* == */
  height: auto;
  /* == */
}

.mcd-menu li ul li a i {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.mcd-menu li ul li ul {
  left: 230px;
  top: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
}

.mcd-menu li ul li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  /*left: -14px;*/
  /* == */
  left: -9px;
  /* == */
  border-right: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}

.mcd-menu li ul li:hover>ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .mcd-menu {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .mcd-menu {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a {
    height: 30px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a i {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a strong {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a small {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a.search input {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a.search buton {
    padding: 8px 10px 9px 10px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li>ul {
    min-width: 180px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li:hover>ul {
    min-width: 180px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li>ul,
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li>ul {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li:hover>ul {
    left: 180px;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li:hover>ul {
    left: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul a i {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mcd-menu {
    width: 50px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a small {
    display: none;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a strong {
    display: none;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a:hover strong,
  .mcd-menu li a.active strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #e67e22;
    color: #FFF;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mcd-menu li .search {
    display: none;
  }
  .mcd-menu li>ul {
    min-width: 180px;
    left: 70px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li:hover>ul {
    min-width: 180px;
    left: 50px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li>ul,
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li>ul {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li:hover>ul {
    left: 180px;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li>ul {
    left: 35px;
    top: 45px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 4px solid #e67e22;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li>ul:before {
    left: 30px;
    top: -9px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #e67e22;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul li ul li:hover>ul {
    left: 30px;
    min-width: 150px;
    top: 35px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li ul a i {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .mcd-menu {
    width: 50px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a small {
    display: none;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a strong {
    display: none;
  }
  .mcd-menu li a:hover strong,
  .mcd-menu li a.active strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #e67e22;
    color: #FFF;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mcd-menu li .search {
    /* placeholder */
  }
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-menu container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar fixed-top bg-light">
    <ul class="mcd-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#Menu_1" title="Overview">
          <i class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></i><strong>Overview</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Menu_2" title="Terms of Use (Licence)">
          <i class="fa fa-certificate fa-lg"></i><strong>Terms</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Menu_3" title="System Requirements">
          <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i><strong>System</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      
         
         <!-- include pop out sub menus for accounting -->
        
         <li>
<a href="#Menu_20" title="Accounting" >
<i class="fa fa-money fa-lg"></i><strong>Accounting</strong>
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_21">
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg"></i>Income
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_49"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Customers</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_50"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Aged Analysis</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_51"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Prepayments</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_52"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Documents</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_22">
<i class="fa fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i>Purchases
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_53"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Vendors</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_54"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Aged Analysis</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_55"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Documents</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_56"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Invoices</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_23">
<i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"></i>General Ledger
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_57"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Records and Transactions</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_58"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Journals</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_59"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Multiple Journals</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_24">
<i class="fa fa-university fa-lg"></i>Banks
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_60"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Accounts</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_61"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Payments</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_62"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Receipts</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_63"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Transfer</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_64"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Transactions</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_25">
<i class="fa fa-envelope-open fa-lg"></i>Invoicing
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_65"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Detailed</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_66"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Ad-Hoc</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_67"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Monthly</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_68"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Assessments</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_69"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Late Fees</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_70"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Violation Fines</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_26">
<i class="fa fa-calculator fa-lg"></i>Financials
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_71"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Trial Balance</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_72"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Audit Trail</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_27">
<i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i>Utilities
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_73"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Incomplete</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_74"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Opening</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_75"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Paid Flags</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_28">
<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg"></i>Reports
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_76"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Cash Flow</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_77"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>P&L and Balance Sheet</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_78"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Income</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_79"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Purchases</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_80"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>General Ledger</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_81"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Statements</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
</div>

   <div class="body-content" id="main">
<p id="top-row"> </p>
<div class="d-flex align-items-right justify-content-right flex-column gap-4">
<form class="d-flex">
<input class="form-control me-1" autocomplete="off" type="search" id="SearchTextBox" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>



UPDATE
I changed "navbar" to "nav" and added this css
.nav {
position: fixed;
top: 50px;

}
I then noticed that any controls on the content page were now active - BUT - the menu items appeared under "card" elements. If I removed bootstrap css it worked apart from some hr that still bleed through - I think this is to do with some position:relative styling. But getting there :-)
